# password_verify() with generated hash from Myth-auth returns false

Tags: codeigniter-4

I know that Myth-auth is not stable yet, but it's okay that's not my point.
I want to make a *change password feature* so I wrote this in my controller:

```
$oldPass=$this->request->getPost('oldPass');
$check=password_verify($oldPass, user()->password_hash);

//Myth-auth has helper to get field data in database using user()->column_name function

var_dump($check);die;
```

I don't know what's wrong with my code, but it returns false.
so I checked again using a hardcoded password like this:

```
$check=password_verify('bayusetiaji14', user()->password_hash);
//using double qoutes
$check2=password_verify("bayusetiaji14", user()->password_hash);
```

but it's still returning false, is this a Myth-auth bug when hashing password or anything else?

Comment: `echo user()->password_hash;` what does it output?

Comment: ```user () -> password_hash```  function is to retrieve the value of 'password_hash' field from the `users` table

Comment: yes ok, but does it have any value? try debugging it!

Comment: return this value dude ```$2y$10$t0jURahLsk5/XW/QbUWpOT5NVYkRxiJl6H.kl3BCYvUrSHc9SKDG``` , that value is auto generated from myth-auth using PASSWORD_DEFAULT algoritm

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oTqT6.png)

because they used base64 encode to manipulate string on they password, you should look on auth->src->entities->user.php

Answer (score 0):

it seems that the library is using double hashes. use this

```
if(!password_verify(base64_encode(hash('sha384', service('request')->getPost('newPasswords'), true)), $oldpassword)){
echo 'password not match'
} else {
echo 'password matched';
}
```